# All activities are closing on home button press

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

Thank you for taking the time to help.

I have created an **Android application** thats starts up with a `splash screen`, then depending if the user is logged in, the application opens either the `login` or `main activity.`

When the user presses the **home button** and then click's the **application icon** I would like the application to resume at the last activity the user was at (For example the login screen).

This works fine when the APK is installed onto the device via Android Studio, but if I try to install the APK manually (the exact same APK), every time I press the home button and reopen the application it acts as if I killed and then started the application (The splash screen starts again).

Any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: PLEASE POST YOUR CODE ..

Comment: Code for what? I expected this to be an automatic behaviour of Android. Surely pressing the home button and then reopening the application should resume the application how it was left.

Comment: Hmm but creating spalsh screen not have any prob with related to version @Aidan

Comment: android:nohistory="true" in manifest...

Answer (score 0):

add following line to your manifest in your launching activity means 1st activity

```
  android:launchMode="singleTask" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

on other activities add:

```
  android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

Comment: By other activities, do you mean every other activity within the application, or just the activities that the splash screen can open (Login and Main)?

Comment: all others activities

Comment: This doesn't work, but reading the documentation it appears this does the opposite of what I would like. I want the application to start how I left it, not finish all activities and open the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is already the default behaviour of Android, but there is one possible way this can happen which is if your device need more space in memory then it may kill other applications which are on pause state. I believe that you're running into that situation and i'm afraid you don't have anything to avoid that.

[Refer to](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

**Edit:** By the way, you can check that by logging something onDestroy and onPause method to see when your activity pauses and when it gets destroyed by system. Until it gets destroyed, you should be able to see the behaviour what you seek.

Comment: I've just realised that this only occurs with a Signed APK and not minSdkVersion < 9. I don't believe it is a memory issue as it works fine on the debug signed APK and I'm using a device with a lot of free memory.

Comment: "I've just realised that this only occurs with a Signed APK" this is strange, but i would say minSdkVersion < 9 is the issue. Just guessing, but there may be a change set on version 9 about this attitude. Sorry for being unable to help then...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.

Сhange `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to `android:launchMode="singleTop"` helped me.